# Loop through list of nested dictionaries

Tags: python

I have an array of dictionaries as follows :

```
test = [
  {
    'name': '30 d',
    'description': [
                      {'label': 'fuel_type', 'value': 'DIESEL'},
                      {'label': 'displacement[cc]', 'value': '2993'},
                      {'label': 'power[hp]', 'value': '208'}, 
                      {'label': 'power[PS]', 'value': '211'},
                      {'label': 'power[kW]', 'value': '155'}
                    ],
    'href': 'http://ws.indicata.com/cherry-rs/api/vivi/BE?body=4954&category=PASSENGER&model=24&engine=9434&regdate=2017&make=39&facelift=1569', 'type': 'application/json', 'rel': 'engine'
  },
  {
    'name': '30 c',
    'description': [
                      {'label': 'fuel_type', 'value': 'DIESEL'},
                      {'label': 'displacement[cc]', 'value': '2993'},
                      {'label': 'power[hp]', 'value': '255'},
                      {'label': 'power[PS]', 'value': '258'},
                      {'label': 'power[kW]', 'value': '190'}
                    ],
    'href': 'http://ws.indicata.com/cherry-rs/api/vivi/BE?body=4954&category=PASSENGER&model=24&engine=7975&regdate=2017&make=39&facelift=1569', 'type': 'application/json', 'rel': 'engine'
  },
  {
    'name': '35 i',
    'description': [
                    {'label': 'fuel_type', 'value': 'PETROL'},
                    {'label': 'displacement[cc]', 'value': '2979'},
                    {'label': 'power[hp]', 'value': '302'},
                    {'label': 'power[PS]', 'value': '306'},
                    {'label': 'power[kW]', 'value': '225'}
                  ],
    'href': 'http://ws.indicata.com/cherry-rs/api/vivi/BE?body=4954&category=PASSENGER&model=24&engine=7977&regdate=2017&make=39&facelift=1569', 'type': 'application/json', 'rel': 'engine'
  }
]
```

I want to loop through it and I want to get something like :

```
Diesel
30 d     155kw     2993cc     211
30 c     190kw     2993cc     258

Petrol
35 i     225kw     2979cc     306
```

Any idea how can I do that?

I'm new to python, thus any help would be welcome.

Comment: @asongtoruin Unfortunately no. This is what I get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing what data/collection type you want your result to be, the following will print the results you want.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

engines = OrderedDict()  
engines['DIESEL'] = []
engines['PETROL'] = []

for engine in test:
    eng_type = engine['description'][0]['value']
    name = engine['name']
    disp = engine['description'][1]['value']
    ps = engine['description'][3]['value']
    kw = engine['description'][4]['value']
    engines[eng_type].append([name, kw, disp, ps])


for engine_type, engine_list in engines.items():
    print(engine_type)
    for engine_vals in engine_list:
        print('{}\t{}kw\t{}cc\t{}'.format(*engine_vals))
    print()
```

Output:

```
DIESEL
30 d    155kw   2993cc  211
30 c    190kw   2993cc  258

PETROL
35 i    225kw   2979cc  306
```

Answer (score 2):

The first step is iterating over each item in the initial list. It looks like each item can be considered a car. Then you just need to extract all the pieces of information you're interested in. 
Since you want the car_type to be printed as a title, store the information using a dictionary with the key as the car_type and the value a list that contains the information for all the cars that fall into this car type.

```
test = [
  {
    'name': '30 d',
    'description': [
                      {'label': 'fuel_type', 'value': 'DIESEL'},
                      {'label': 'displacement[cc]', 'value': '2993'},
                      {'label': 'power[hp]', 'value': '208'}, 
                      {'label': 'power[PS]', 'value': '211'},
                      {'label': 'power[kW]', 'value': '155'}
                    ],
    'href': 'http://ws.indicata.com/cherry-rs/api/vivi/BE?body=4954&category=PASSENGER&model=24&engine=9434&regdate=2017&make=39&facelift=1569', 'type': 'application/json', 'rel': 'engine'
  },
  {
    'name': '30 c',
    'description': [
                      {'label': 'fuel_type', 'value': 'DIESEL'},
                      {'label': 'displacement[cc]', 'value': '2993'},
                      {'label': 'power[hp]', 'value': '255'},
                      {'label': 'power[PS]', 'value': '258'},
                      {'label': 'power[kW]', 'value': '190'}
                    ],
    'href': 'http://ws.indicata.com/cherry-rs/api/vivi/BE?body=4954&category=PASSENGER&model=24&engine=7975&regdate=2017&make=39&facelift=1569', 'type': 'application/json', 'rel': 'engine'
  },
  {
    'name': '35 i',
    'description': [
                    {'label': 'fuel_type', 'value': 'PETROL'},
                    {'label': 'displacement[cc]', 'value': '2979'},
                    {'label': 'power[hp]', 'value': '302'},
                    {'label': 'power[PS]', 'value': '306'},
                    {'label': 'power[kW]', 'value': '225'}
                  ],
    'href': 'http://ws.indicata.com/cherry-rs/api/vivi/BE?body=4954&category=PASSENGER&model=24&engine=7977&regdate=2017&make=39&facelift=1569', 'type': 'application/json', 'rel': 'engine'
  }
]

to_print = {}
for car in test:
  car_type = car['description'][0]['value'].title()
  name = car['name']
  power_kw = car['description'][4]['value'] + 'kw'
  displacement = car['description'][1]['value'] + 'cc'
  power_ps = car['description'][3]['value']

  try:
    to_print[car_type].append('\t'.join([name, power_kw, displacement, power_ps]))
  except KeyError:
    to_print[car_type] = []
    to_print[car_type].append('\t'.join([name, power_kw, displacement, power_ps]))

for car_type in to_print:
  print(car_type)
  for row in to_print[car_type]:
    print(row)
```